# Appending with jQuery using Razor syntax

Tags: jquery, razor

Can anyone tell me how to append this part of coe:

```
$("#TjedneTempSchedul").append('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="MyTable"><thead style="background-color: #393a44;"><tr style="color:white;"><th></th><th>PON</th></tr></thead> @{var pon = "";var klasa = "";}');
```

Anybody know how to deal with `@{var pon = "";var klasa = "";}` part?

I tried to put `@@{var pon = "";var klasa = "";}`, but it didn't work, any other way to properly append that?

Comment: Whats the use of `@{var pon = "";var klasa = "";} `?

Comment: Given that the block of Razor code is only setting two variables and not outputting anything, what output are you expecting?

Comment: it seems you are putting at wrong place.

Comment: I am just setting two variables but later in code i am using them inside table, this is just a part of code. This @{var pon = "";var klasa = "";} is set just after thread but since it is inside table which i am appending from jquery a need that to be appended properly. If i set it to @@ then output is@{var pon = "";var klasa = "";} as a text and i see it in page instead to be razor syntax

Comment: `</table>` closing tag is missing

Comment: Razor code is of no use when appending it using JavaScript/jQuery as jQuery  executes on client side and razor code on server side. You need to change the approach

Comment: Why don't you put `@{var pon = "";var klasa = "";}` in your html inside `<div id="TjedneTempSchedul"></div>`?

Comment: I am making dynamic table, based on results i get, and it works when i use viewbag from controler and make table in view. But now i get results for table in jquery so i tried to append everything :D. Gues i need another approach :). Ty guys for replies.

Comment: adiga- that is my nex step to put everything in html and apend just table body from jquery.